# AngularJS NOT WORKING in LARAVEL docker continer

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, laravel, docker

**I've been following this** [tutorial](http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-eloquent-orm) 
and the problem is when I go to localhost I get this:

[image]

***Someone sees the problem?***

**I'm running LAravel5 in focker container** [dockervel](http://www.spiralout.eu/2015/12/dockervel-laravel-development.html)

**To install node modules in this container project I run**

```
dnodejs npm install
```

This is the error!

```
localhost/:65 The specified value "{{email}}" is not a valid email address.
http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/js/bootstrap.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
employees.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'controller' of undefined
http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Please provide your code. Also check your browser's error console for any information. Usually when it shows code like this, something is mistyped somewhere.

Comment: Ok, I've updated with the error log. The code is same like in the tutorial http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-angularjs-tutorial

Comment: Have you included the angular.min.js file, and before including your controllers? (Line 102 under "Displaying data from the REST API using AngularJS") .. Edit: Your problem is here: http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). It needs to be the PUBLIC path to the file.

Comment: I see I'm missing those files. But when I want to  download them it seems that there are not available at the site, right after the title of the tutorial is a link to get .zip but I get 404. Can I somehow not include them?

Comment: No, they are required in order for everything to work. It should have been installed automatically by laravel, probably in `public/libs/angular/angular/angular.js`. `public` would not be used in the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker build + private NPM (+ private docker hub)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30573501/docker-build-private-npm-private-docker-hub)